# Создание View рядом с другим View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Всем привет! Собираю программу на стороннем движке. Xcode и obj-c не знаю совсем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему с созданием видов.

В XIB имеется Window без кастомного класса, ViewController с классом RunnerViewController, а так же View с классом EAGLView (внутри ViewController). На этот вид есть ссылка g_glView. Доступа к классу ViewController'а нет. Все *.m файлы спрятаны в .*a бибилиотеку.
Задача: показать сторонний баннер. Если я показываю его внутри g_glView - то приложение крашится. Вероятно, баннер не поддерживает рендер с OpenGL.

```
extern *UIView g_glView.
[theInterstitiel show:g_glView]; //crash
```

Если я програмно добавлю свой View, через rootViewController, то происходит в точности тоже самое. Полагаю rootViewController это и есть контроллер с классом RunnerViewController. И мой вид добавляется к виду EAGLView, который рисует в OpenGL.

```
static UIView *promoview;
static UIViewController *promocont;
promoview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
promocont = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[promocont.view addSubview: promoview];
[theInterstitiel show:promoview]; //crash
```

Однако, если я добавляю свой вид к Window, то приложение не крашится.

```
static UIView *promoview;
promoview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIWindow* promowindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[promowindow addSubview: promoview];
[theInterstitiel show:promoview];
```

Но при этом, мой вид лежит выше всех остальных и при нажатии на баннер, окошко с AppStore появляется за ним и его не видно.

Вопрос: можно ли добавить свой вид не как SubView основного вида EAGLView, а рядом с ним, но чтобы он был выше основного вида EAGLView?

Answer (score 1):

рядом добавить нельзя, вью должен быть или выше или ниже (по z order) соседних вью. Попробуй просто скрывать свой вид после клика.
Плюс посмотри на саму причину креша. Возможно там другая причина